# React native 0.64 iOS release build stuck on 'Bundle React native code and images'

Tags: react-native

**Description**

Hello. Since I have updated my react native project from 0.63.4 to 0.64, I fail to build it on iOS in release mode.
The build block on the "Bundle React Native code and images" phase and never ends.

I have tried to:

- watchman watch-del-all, uninstall and reinstall watchman
- deintegrate and setup cocoapods
- use react-native upgrade
- upgrade by hand with react native upgrade helper

Everything works as expected on Android and on iOS debug mode.

build return :
Run custom shell script 'Bundle React Native code and images'

this build phase never ends

[image]
[image]

**React Native version:**

```
System:
OS: macOS 11.2.3
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 290.03 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.15.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/node
Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.14.8 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 14.4, DriverKit 20.2, macOS 11.1, tvOS 14.3, watchOS 7.2
Android SDK:
Android NDK: 20.0.5594570
IDEs:
Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119
Xcode: 12.4/12D4e - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.9 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.64.0 => 0.64.0
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found
```

**Steps To Reproduce**

Provide a detailed list of steps that reproduce the issue.

Update a project to RN 0.64 using ncu and npm install
Update every single file one by one using react native grade helper
Clean build-cache, watchman watch-del-all
Try to compile on Release mode in the simulator or real device
Expected Results

Build successfully

Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository:

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "wallstreat_bet",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bankify/react-native-animate-number": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^6.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.43.6",
    "react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.23",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-generator": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.4.3",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0",
    "uuid-random": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

podfile:
[image]

Comment: Same issue here, did you fix it?

Comment: For me, it takes 58 minutes for the release build to finish